# Adding View to Relative Layout behind an existing view causes screen flicker

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm trying to insert a `View` behind another view that is taking up the full screen and then later removing the view in the front to reveal the only remaining view. Functionally, everything is working as expected but the problem is that when I call **View.addView()** to add the second view, specifying to add it at index 0 so it is behind the first view, the screen flickers. It's almost as if the view is actually getting added in front of the first view for a fraction of a second and then it is hidden again as it is moved behind it.

Here's what I'm doing:

When the Activity is created I add an `ImageView` to a `RelativeLayout` and make the `RelativeLayout` instance the Activity's content view:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

    super.onCreate(bundle);

    m_layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    m_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    m_splashImage = new ImageView(this);
    m_splashImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.splash);
    m_splashImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    m_layout.addView(m_splashImage, 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    setContentView(m_layout);
}
```

When the **Activity** is started, I created and add the `GLSurfaceView` to the `RelativeLayout` at index 0, so it is behind the `ImageView`:

```
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    m_layout.addView(new MyGLSurfaceView(), 0, 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
}
```

Later, after all of the loading is done and the GLSurfaceView is ready to continuously render, 
the splash `ImageView` is removed and cleaned up.

```
public void hideSplashScreen() {

   if (m_splashImage != null) {
        m_layout.removeView(m_splashImage);
        m_splashImage = null;
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't require creating the `GLSurfaceView` before the **onStart()** is called?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)` on of the view that you adding behind? Of course before you are adding it.